# Let $I=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. For $x\in \mathbb{R} $, let $\phi (x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,\text{I})$, then which of the following is true?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

> Let $I=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. For $x\in \mathbb{R} $ let $\phi \{x\}=\operatorname{dist}(x,\text{I})=\inf\{|x-y|:y\in \text{I}\}$. Then
>
> 1. $\phi(x)$ is discontinuous somewhere on $\mathbb{R}$.
> 2. $\phi(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but not continuously differentiable exactly at $x=0$.
> 3. $\phi(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but not continuously differentiable exactly at $x=0$ and $x=1$.
> 4. $\phi(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have never thought about the continuity of distance function. Now with this problem, I am facing problems on how to approach to solve this. I don't know how to check differentiability nor continuity for this function, as I have not the slightest idea. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: could you try to evaluate this function for some sample $x$ and plot its graph ?

Comment: Yes, I have plotted the graph and got the picture. @Mirko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

We have $\phi(x) = \max(-x,0,x-1)$. If you plot this you should be able to guess & prove your answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard to compute $\phi(x)$: if $x<0$ then $\phi(x)=|x|$, if $0\leq x\leq 1$ then $\phi(x)=0$, and if $x>1$ then $\phi(x)=|x-1|=x-1$. Can you answer the four questions now?

Comment: Yes, I have plotted the graph and it's all clear now. thanks